# Random PC lockups - What else can I try?

Tags: hardware-failure, freeze, windows-11

I have an Asus ROG G20BM which is about 5 years old. When its running its a decent PC so I am reluctant to replace it but I have a really odd random freezing issue which I have tried everything for.

Here are my specs:

```
Processor AMD FX(tm)-770K Quad Core Processor 3.50 GHz 
Installed RAM 12.0 GB 
Windows 11 Home 64-bit 
256GB Kensington SSD 
Graphics AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
```

I can be working away, and for no apparent reason it will just lock up. No error messges, no bluescreens, just whatever is on screen stops. The mouse and keyboard will not respond but the screen stays on and it remains powered up.
The only way I can un-freeze it is by forcing it to power down and back up again.

This happens so randomly, I cannot put any pattern to it or replicate it. Sometimes it will happen just after boot and it will freeze when idle and other times it can be after days of being left on and it will happen mid game.

When it happens nothing gets logged, its as though the whole OS locks up so it cannot log. The only thing that then appears is a kernel error when I have powered it down ungracefully.

Things I have tried:

```
Reinstalled Windows 10
Upgraded to Windows 11
Upgraded BIOS
Upgraded all drivers
Uninstalled AV
Ran Malware scans
Disabled GPU
Ran MemTest
Ran SFC
Stress test
```

Can anyone suggest any other toold to help diagnose what the issue is or have any suggestions what I can do to rule out what its not? Any suggestions are grately appreciated!

Comment: I suggest that you power it off, remove the mains lead, take the side cover off, then undo and reconnect all the connectors inside. If in doubt about how any of the connectors go together, ask here. (E.g., the power connectors on the motherboard usually have a little tab you have to squeeze to remove the connector, and you have to make sure the connector is pushed home enough for the tab to engage.)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton I will try this. I don't know if you have seen the inside of one of these but they are horrible and compact so while I have it open, I might replace the themal paste just to rule that out too.

Comment: If you're confident with replacing the thermal paste, you might as well re-seat the graphics card and the RAM too. If the heatsink won't come off easily, you can heat it with something like a hairdryer to try to soften the paste - pulling it too hard could result in damaged pins on the CPU, from what I understand.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes, reseating RAM could help -- but I'd be leery of moving the CPU or heat sink, as it is very easy to make matters worse, or even destroy the CPU or PCB under it.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnose the hardware

Step 1 Find voltage monitors software compatible with your motherboard.

Check that the 3.3v,5v, and 12v are all within 5% above or below the correct voltage.

Step 2 While the software is running run Furmark running its benchmark for at least 20mins to see if that cause your problem.

If the voltage drops below 5% (12v min is 11.4v), your power supply is too small,bad, or etc and needs replacing with a larger one.

If the system doesn't crash within about 20 mins or so its time to start looking else where.

Repeat the same test, but this time run Prime95, and see if that causes your system to freeze.

Also bad sectors can freeze your system for long periods of time 10+ minutes.

To combat this we need to run

```
chkdsk /r c:
```

Type Y and enter to do this process after a reboot. This could take hours to run, but on your 256gb ssd it should be 20-40mins depending what it finds.